# PNG occasionally loses data on way from Flash to server

Tags: flash, png

we've been stumped on this and would love some help!

Our users are creating TIFs in Flash and posting the image data in Base64 via HTTP POST to an ASPX server that receives it with:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Form["ImgData"]  );
```

We find that the method works but in one of 20-30 or so cases the amount of data received by the server differs from what the client claims to be sending.  ASPX code:

```
dataLengthSentFromClient = Request.Form["dataLengthFromClient"].ToString();
<>
ReceivedBytesLength=Request.Form["ImgData"].Length.ToString();
```

but the other 24 times it seems to be working fine.  Any ideas?  Should we not pass data this way from Flash to the server?

---

(Here is the client AS code)
        var image:BitmapData;

```
if (toTrim) {
tempBitmapData=new BitmapData(workingSrc.width,workingSrc.height,true,0x00000000);
tempBitmapData.draw(workingSrc);
var tempBitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(tempBitmapData,PixelSnapping.ALWAYS,true);
bounds=tempBitmapData.getColorBoundsRect(0xFF000000,0x00000000,false);
var letterMatrix:Matrix=new Matrix(1,0,0,1,- bounds.x,- bounds.y);
tempBitmap.transform.matrix=letterMatrix;
image=new BitmapData(bounds.width,bounds.height,true,0x00000000);
image.draw(tempBitmap,letterMatrix);
} else {
image=new BitmapData(workingSrc.width,workingSrc.height,true,0x00000000);
image.draw(workingSrc,letterMatrix);
}


var bytes:ByteArray=PNGEncoder.encode(image);
var base64Bytes:String=Base64.encodeByteArray(bytes);

var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.activityID=activityID;
vars.imgData=base64Bytes;
vars.dataLengthFromSarah=vars.imgData.length;
vars.activityLocation=activityLoc;
vars.op="writePNG";
if (fileName!=null) {
vars.filename=fileName;
}
// Save info about the variables passed in case we need to dump error data
dispatchEvent(new DumpPrepEvent(vars.toString()));

var url:URLRequest=new URLRequest(INTERFACE);
url.data=vars;
url.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
```

Comment: This is good to know to save on traffic but I'm not sure it's causing the occasional transfer failure. 

The packages we use: 
  
    com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder; 
and
    and com.hurlant.util.Base64;

Comment: The cache question is interesting.  I will look into that.  Do you recommend a more reliable way of transferring the image data from Flash?  I'm happy to change it if it could help!

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I could imagine(assuming every library you use works right) is that base64 symbols are urlencoded but not urldecoded. Base64 have '+' which would be urlencoded during post transfer, and I'm not sure this ASPX library does urldecode on it's own.  The probability of errors in this case is higher than 1/25 even for a few bytes of random data. But it may be you are using non-random test data with a small size.

Comment: The same PNG can be sent up and fail the first time but go through the second time.  It makes me think that wouldn't be related to Base64 encoding, no?